# LinqKit: AsExpandable not working

Tags: c#, linq, linqkit

**Code:**

```
public static GetRows()
        {

            var to_ret = db.TableRows.Select(x=> new TableRowModel(
            {
                TableRowId = x.TableRowId,
                Type = x.Type,
                Name = x.Name,
                CreatedAt = x.CreatedAt,
                ModifiedAt = x.ModifiedAt,
                Enums = x.Enums.AsExpandable().Select(y => y.ToEnumModel())
            });
            return to_ret;
        }

public static EnumModel ToEnumModel(this Enum x)
        {
            var to_ret = new EnumModel()
            {
                CFPId = x.CFPId,
                CreatedAt = x.CreatedAt,
                ModifiedAt = x.ModifiedAt,
            };
            return to_ret;
        }
```

Running `GetRows` gives error saying:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable1[Test.Models.Enum]
>   `AsExpandable[Enum]`(System.Linq.IQueryable1[Test.Models.Enum])' method,
>   and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Even tried putting `AsExpandable`like `db.TableRows.AsExpandable().Select`. Doesn't work.

Comment: Ohk, I have corrected the error message.

Comment: Removed comments that no longer apply.

Comment: Add LinqKit from Nuget and it should be working fine. Here is a link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/