# EF comparing Expression<Func<T, bool>> with T

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can we compare `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` with `T` in Entity Framework?

For example:

```
Expression<Func<Book, bool>> exp = getYellowBooksExpr();
var v = context.Books.Where(exp).ToList();
```

This above code would run well, but how can we run a query like this:

```
var v = context.Students.Where(x => x.Book == exp).ToList();
```

Comment: Instead of an `Expression<Func<Book, bool>>`, don't you want a `Predicate<Book>`?

Comment: Event if it was possible (it's not), `x.Book == exp` makes no sense when `exp` returns `bool`

Comment: We have a large sets of Expression<Func<T, bool>> we use all over our application and we want to use the same conditions instead of duplicate them for Predicate<Book>.

Comment: Related: [Entity Framework Filter "Expression<Func<T, bool>>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337692/entity-framework-filter-expressionfunct-bool)

Comment: @IvanStoev I mentioned == just for a placeholder for the real expression. Maybe I should have written ?? instead. I saw expressions like: exp.Invoke(x.Book) by using LinqKit but, somhow, it doesn't work for us.

Comment: you can make an extension on the `IQueryable`.  see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46895066/using-extension-method-in-linq-to-entities/46896295#46896295) answer

Comment: with x=>exp.Compile().Invoke(x.Book) you can do what you described, but it won't be translatable into SQL (so you'll have to filter in memory after query execution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the following

**Edited** based on the comment below

```
var students = context.Students.Where(t=>context.Books                               
                     .Where(exp).Contains(t.Book));
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: I think just `context.Books.Where(exp).Contains(t.Book)` would work.

Comment: I edited the answer based on your comment. When I wrote the answer I felt that comparing the object might fail.. hope this hint helps in solving the question

Comment: EF should translate entity comparisons into SQL that compares the  primary key.

Comment: Running SQL trace, I found it "SQL killer" but it works. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in general without rewriting your `Where` expression. But you can use external library, like LinqKit, to do that rewriting for you. Install LinqKit nuget package, then you can do:

```
var v = context.Students.AsExpandable()
          .Where(x => exp.Invoke(x.Book)).ToList();
```

This will work for more complex cases too:

```
var v = context.Students.AsExpandable()
          .Where(x => x.Name == "something" || exp.Invoke(x.Book)).ToList();
```

Comment: I've tried to prevent using this library but it seems like this is the only way indeed. Thank you